# Access nested data without too many foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to do a "deep loop" on a large data-set in order to access some nested values (for a DB insert).

Currently I have the following code, which works, however it is very slow and ends up timing out before all the data has finished processing. I can't figure out how to get to the nested data without doing so many loops.

**Sample Array:**

```
$resultArray = [
  {
    "item1": "value",
    "item2": "value",
    "item3": "value",
    "item4": "value",
    "item5": [
      {
        "anothervalue1": "value",
        "anothervalue2": "value",
        "anothervalue3": "value",
        "anothervalue4": "value",
        "anothervalue5": "value"        
      },
      {
        "anothervalue1": "value",
        "anothervalue2": "value",
        "anothervalue3": "value",
        "anothervalue4": "value",
        "anothervalue5": "value" 
      },
      {
        "anothervalue1": "value",
        "anothervalue2": "value",
        "anothervalue3": "value",
        "anothervalue4": "value",
        "anothervalue5": "value" 
      }
      {
        // another 150+
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**Current Implementation:**

```
// Loop over main array
foreach ($resultArray as $object) {
  // Loop over each object
  foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 'item5') {
      // Loop over each 'item5' object
      foreach ($value as $history_key => $history_value) {
        foreach ($history_value as $history_deep_key => $history_deep_value) {
            $arr = array( 
                $_GET['someparam'], // column1 data
                $object['item1'], // column2 data
                $_GET['anotherparam'], // column3 data
                $object['item2'], // column4 data
                $history_value['anothervalue1'], // column5 data
                $history_value['anothervalue2'], // column6 data
                $history_value['anothervalue3'], // column7 data
                $history_value['anothervalue4'], // column8 data
                $history_value['anothervalue5'], // column9 data
                $object['item3'] // column10 data
            );
            $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO reporting_clients(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10)
                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $statement->execute($arr);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Is it possible to access the nested data wihtout so many `foreach` loops?**

Comment: if you know the keys. then yes you can access the data directly.

Comment: if you don't know the keys then this would be the best way to access the data.  Could could also turn it into a function it you need to re-use it many times.  `in_array` may prove helpful as well

Comment: Show me your original code. so based on that I can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible if you know to what value to access and you know the keys and structure of object array you have or any array.

in your case. e-g

```
$value = $resultArray[0]->item5[0]->anothervalue5;
echo $value;
```

if its a multidimentional array and not object array just change the arrows with array boxes.

```
$value = $resultArray[0]['item5'][0]['anothervalue5'];
echo $value;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!